# Tiles2 not working with struts2

Tags: java, apache, struts2, tiles2

I am working on struts2 and using tiles in my application we use Netbeans7.1. But we got an error "The module has not been deployed.See the server log for details."

> "Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Rule"

we add listener in `web.xml`

**web.xml file**

```
 <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>

    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>

</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

struts.xml file

Comment: Which Tiles version and which Struts2 version do you use? Do you have struts2-tiles plugin in your classpath? Stacktrace from Server Log?

Comment: struts2-tiles-plugin-2.1.6.jar, xwork-core-2.2.1.1.jar, struts2-core-2.2.1.1.jar, commons-collections-3.1.jar, commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar, commons-io-1.3.2.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, freemarker-2.3.16.jar, javassist-3.7.ga.jar, ognl-2.6.11.jar, struts2-dojo-plugin-2.2.1.1.jar, tiles-api-2.0.6.jar, tiles-jsp-2.0.6.jar   We use this jars in my application

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Struts2 Tiles Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/tiles-plugin.html) Documentation.

You web.xml should look a little bit different then yours.

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And don't forget to add apache common digester jar to your lib folder.